# How to click on a link inside span inside <a class> with using xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

Using xpath, sélénium doesn't recognize the element, what's the correct xpath?

HTML:

```
<a class="xmi" onclick="this.focus();return false; "href="#">
 <span title="">SITE A</span>
</a>
```

My XML locator file:

```
<domElements>
   <name>Site_A</name>
   <locators>
      <type>XPATH</type>
      <value>//span[contains(@title,'SITE A')]</value>
      <priority>0</priority>
   </locators>
      </domElements>
```

Java code calling my locator:

```
this.locate("Site_A").click();

}
```

}

Comment: Is there a locate by link text option? Try "SITE A" as link text.

Comment: Is that really what the HTML has? It looks invalid because of the space right before the closing quote of your onClick event.  When I run it through an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) I get an error that reads “No space between attributes.
At line 1, column 53
return false; "href="#">.   The error is gone when I simply move onClick’s closing quote over one space to ensure there is a space before the href attribute.

Comment: @jeffC not it doesn't work ,

Comment: @C.Peck the site/html is provided by the client and it does work when i click on the link

Answer (score 0):

`SITE A` is not the title (which is an empty string in this case), it's the element text. Use `text()` or `.` to locate it

```
//span[contains(., 'SITE A')]
```

If the element is inside `<iframe>` you need to swith to it first

```
driver.switchTo().frame("afr::PushIframe");
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath ,  i think i need to locate it from a class > span > title but i tried many times

Comment: @RoughTime Is this inside `<iframe>`?

Comment: iframe is opened and closed from the start   <iframe name="afr::PushIframe" id="afr::PushIframe" style="display:none" src="/fscmUI/afr/blank.html"></iframe>

Comment: @RoughTime You need to switch to it first, updated the answer.

Comment: i added DriverPageSwitcher.switchToLastPAge(this.webDriver) , usually this is what i use to switch but it's the same

Comment: @RoughTime I have no idea what `DriverPageSwitcher.switchToLastPAge` is or what it does. Try to use the code from my answer and make sure there aren't any nested frames.

Answer (score 0):

`SITE A` is not the *value* attribute but the *innerHTML*, so you need to:

```
<domElements>
   <name>Site_A</name>
   <locators>
      <type>XPATH</type>
      <value>//span[@title and text()='SITE A']</value>
      <priority>0</priority>
   </locators>
</domElements>
```

As an alternative you can also change the `<value>` to include the parent node as:

```
<domElements>
   <name>Site_A</name>
   <locators>
      <type>XPATH</type>
      <value>//a[@class='xmi']/span[@title and text()='SITE A']</value>
      <priority>0</priority>
   </locators>
</domElements>
```

Comment: thank you, but it's still not working , the only way that it worked for me is by using a global Xpath using a chrome plugin and it's not a good idea